# Why am I unable to apply a color to ⚫ (&#x26ab)?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am unable to apply color to ⚫ (&#x26ab) in Firefox Quantum v60.1.0

I maintain a site that that uses this character with color, but it has been colorless after an upgrade to FF. Still works in IE11.

```html
<b style="color:green;">&#x26ab</b>
```

Is this a bug in FF, or was this a bad practice from the beginning?

Comment: Well according to https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl that's the character for "MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE", so the fact that you could change the color at any point sounds like a bug

Comment: that looks like an emoji to me.

Comment: i dont see the changes in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&#x2B24;` or some other instead. The one you have listed is an Emoji. You could also use a certain web font for this case.

```html
<b style="color:green;">&#x2B24;&#x25CF;</b>
```

Comment: The code snippet is showing a green invalid character on my end. Browser FF Quantum v60.1.0

Comment: @SterlingBeason what font are you trying to display it in?

Comment: It works as expected for me on Firefox Quantum v62.0 (64-bit). Are you running an outdated version of Firefox for a specific reason?

Comment: On the site, font-family: "Segoe UI", "Segoe", Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, but I'm taking about the code snippet preview on SO.

Comment: @SterlingBeason hm theres a lot of factors at play hard to narrow it down.

Comment: @jdgregson Yes, enterprise version. Won't be getting an upgrade anytime soon.

Comment: It's Windows 7's fault. I tested the snippet above on BrowserStack. Using Windows 7, FF 59-62 all show the missing character icon for `&#x2B24;` and correctly display `&#x25CF;`. Using Windows 10, FF 59-62 correctly display both characters.

Comment: @jdgregson could be a difference in the fonts on each system.